# What does ''Kono watashi ga'' mean?

Tags: definitions, anime

I've heard this in an anime but need to understand the definition of it

Comment: Please see the feedback you received on your previous question. Japanese Language Stack Exchange is not a translation service; For that, you can try Google Translate. ;)

Comment: @seafood258 GoogleTranslate does not give an accurate translation I can't do that

Comment: This question *is* basically off-topic.  [Japanese.SE is not a translation service.](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/799)  Please try to include some context and show some research effort in future questions.  Still, I'll wait for others to close vote, just in case someone wants to leave it open anyway, because the use of この with first person pronouns is a rather interesting topic that doesn't translate into English very easily.  (Perhaps the question could be rewritten so that it's on-topic, and we could have an interesting discussion.)

Comment: In the meantime, if you can improve your question by including the context you found it in and telling us what you understand so far, it would greatly increase the odds that the question will remain open.  Please use the *edit* button.

Comment: @user10299 That was a joke. In that case, I don't think Google Translate or JLSE are appropriate places for such a question. Of course, as others have stated, if you were to revise your question...

Comment: Your question might be answered by this: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/what-does-it-mean-when-%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE-is-in-front-of-a-personal-pronoun/16238#16238

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't enough context to judge exactly in what sense it is used, I guess it was similar to この私が〜します. And I also assume that you wonder why there is この before 私.
Here, "Kono watashi ga (この私が)" basically means "I", but it is emphasized. It is also pronounced as "Kono watakushi ga" in more formal way. 
 
Ex:

- もう20歳若ければ、この私が彼女と結婚している: 
   If I was 20 years younger, I'd marry her myself. (Here, not others but I get married to her)
- 驚いたでしょうね、この私が延期してやろうと思うなんて: 
   You are surprised at my wishing to postpone it.
- よかったら、この私がそれを取ってきてあげましょうか?: 
   If it is OK, shall I go get it?

Comment: What does ''Bakana kono watashi ga'' mean I don't what that means heard from a game from youtube?

Comment: Basically, "kono この" here is also used to emphasize "I 私". In game, it is often used as "バカな、この私が(負けるなんて)", which can be loosely translated as "why on earth I could be defeated".